# Clean Architecture/DDD: How to initialise Entities?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, software-design, clean-architecture

According to "Uncle Bobs" book "Clean Architecture" the core of a software system consists of Entities(critical business rules) and Use Cases (A use case is supposed to be an object). A use case models a process flow which interacts with the entities, but how should the use case initialize the entity object? The book explicitly states that you should not pass the entity as an input argument to the use case class. On the other hand: If the input of each use case must contain all data relevant to initialise the entity and the entity is reused in hundreds of use cases, a change of the entity arguments might become painful. If I need another argument in the entity I would have to modify the input of all use cases using that entity.

What is the best approach to that problem?

[Clean architecure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIeK7.png)

Answer (score 2):

> A use case models a process flow which interacts with the entities, but how should the use case initialize the entity object?

Use cases usually retrieve an entity object from a repository by its identity and the repository initializes the entity.

> If the input of each use case must contain all data relevant to initialise the entity and the entity is reused in hundreds of use cases, a change of the entity arguments might become painful.

There are usually rare use cases that create master data, such like a customer or a product. It is the nature of those use cases that you pass them all required properties they need to initialize an entity. After that they use a repository to persist the entities they created so that other use cases can retrieve them later by their id.

If you have a lot of use cases that require all of the entity data, you probably have another desing issue or you just have a lot of creation use cases.

Probably you are implementing an application that doesn't really have use cases, because it is just a nice frontend for database access. In those applications the use case logic is done by the user. The clean architecture doesn't fit in those situations.

Comment: Is it ok for a repository to initialize the entities(?), because this would mean at least a direct data dependency (dependency on the data structure) between the repository and the entities. This would mean a direct reference between "enterprise business rules" and "interface adapters". So to speak we make a "tunnel" through the "application business rule" layer/cycle to bypass it, making two layers dependent on each which should be separated by another layer/cycle

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The use cases use repositories to persist and get entities. The repository implementation is responsible for mapping the entity's state to a persistence object, or representation, and vice versa. But you should never introduce a dependency in the entity to the persistence object. E.g. in Java you can use JPA in the repository implementation as the "persistence representation", but the entities do not have a depencency to any JPA entity.

Answer (score 1):

Generally entities are retrieved from a factory or repository that is injected into the use case.  It is the responsibility of the repository or factory to do the initialization, thus decoupling it from the use case.

The input rarely has all the data needed to initialize an entity, just enough to request that entity from something that *does* have all the data.  For example, a primary key or lookup value.

So, for example, if you had a login use-case. You would accept a username and a password into the use-case.  It does *not* know everything about how to initialize a user that is stored in the database (or ldap, auth service, etc).  All it knows is the user's login and a proposed password.  The login use-case should talk to the user repository and retrieve a user by that login (not necessarily a primary key, but still unique enough to identify a single user).  That repository can return a user entity that you can compare the password to.

Decoupling it this way means you can swap out your repository easily to have a different store, and more importantly, easily test it by mocking it out.

Comment: Is it ok for a repository to initialize the entities(?), because this would mean at least a direct data dependency (dependency on the data structure) between the repository and the entities. This would mean a direct reference between "enterprise business rules" and "interface adapters". So to speak we make a "tunnel" through the "application business rule" layer/cycle to bypass it, making two layers dependent on each which should be separated by another layer/cycle

Comment: Yes, you can always go inwards for your dependency.  This articile: https://medium.com/@gushakov/clean-architecture-domain-entities-and-interface-adapters-4152b9ee22d2 does a nice job talking about instantiating entities from those outer layers (adpaters in general)